# SPA with content management

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, wp-api

I would like to build Single Page Web Application (SPA) with `React.js`.

Application would need some Content Management System for back-end. I was thinking to use `WordPress` and their `REST-API's` but I don't know how to retrieve data from my wordpress installation.

Back-end and front-end would be in different domains so just building WP theme with React.js wouldn't work.

Basically, I don't know how to call and populate data from wordpress to my front-end.

I would need someone to point me to the right direction. And, maybe recommend easier CMS to use in this task.

Comment: Is a paid service an opportunity to manage your content? I think the term you are looking for is „headless cms“. https://www.contentful.com/ is such a service

Comment: It might be, but for the learning reasons it would be better to learn how to make api calls to wordpress since most of my sites are built on WP. @micha149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is very easy to access your WordPress website data through HTTP REST API 
Here you have the full documentation on WordPress REST APi
http://v2.wp-api.org/